# rails 3: on create, how do I validate a 'referral code' form field with a custom method that verifies the referral code exists in another table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

This is probably a simple validation question, but I've only got experience with built-in rails validation helpers such as allowing a field to be blank, and/or enforcing a certain length, or matching a regex.

When a user registers (using Devise) my registration form (and Users schema) also has a "referred_by" field where they can enter a referral code (such as a sales rep ID).

The 'referred_by' field needs some special validation before being saved:
* remove any spaces
* force to lower case
* verify it's an allowable 'referral code' value (exists in ReferralCodes table's "code" field)

If it's not an allowable value (eg, does not exist in the ReferralCode table) I need to flag a validation error on the form such as "That's not a valid referral code"

I have no idea where to put the method to do that so it's triggered automatically as part of rails validation when trying to save data...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a custom validator, with some sanitizing of data in the model.

app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_with ReferralValidator

  before_save :clean_referral

  def clean_referral
    self.referred_by = self.referred_by.strip.lowercase
  end

end
```

app/lib/validators/referral_validator.rb:

```
class ReferralValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    record.errors[:base] << "#{record.referred_by} is not a valid referral code" unless referral_code_valid?
  end
end
```

You'll have to define referral_code_valid? with whatever logic you'd like to classify the referral code being valid, and make sure you add autoloading of the lib directory to your configuration.  You can use the following in config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_path += %W({config.root}/lib)
```

Comment: is there a way to have the validator also highlight the field that failed validation?

Comment: figured it out. changed [:base] to [:FIELDNAME]. I didn't use the separate lib file etc, though, or validates_with, simply put the validation method in the User class and used validate :valid_referral, :on => :create